# XML Documentation: <see> tag with multiple generic type parameters

Tags: c#, generics, xml-documentation

I'm trying to use XML documentation on the members of a class, and in a certain case I would like to reference a generic type using a  tag. The problem here is that a warning is generated when multiple generic type parameters are specified. It was easy enough to find how to reference a generic type with a single parameter, as such:

```
<see cref="Func{int}" />
```

However, trying something like this generates the warning:

```
<see cref="Func{int, bool}" />
```

It seems that I am either using the wrong syntax for references with more than one type parameter, or such references are not currently supported in XML docs for C#. Strangely enough, I can't seem to find any information about this on MSDN or in the Sandcastle docs (which I'm using to compile the documentation, and also complains about the syntax). Any clarification here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the .NET names, not the C# aliases:

```
<see cref="Func{Int32, Boolean}" />
```

Comment: Ah, that solves the issue. I guess it was working for a single type parameter because I was using a custom class in my code. Thanks.