# Display XML comments generic params in Intellisence for static method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xml-comments

I'm having trouble getting the generic parameters for the two methods below to display the types in Intellisence.

For the `IEnumerable<T>` I just simply want it to show as `double`.

[image: Intellisence screenshot for IEnumerable<T> Method]

And for the `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` overload, I want it to show `KeyValuePair<int,string>` but of course without hard-coding the types.

[image: Intellisence screenshot for KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> Method]

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace Common.FluentValidation
{
    public static partial class Validate
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Compares two dictionaries are null or contain equal sets of items.
        /// Returns true if both instances are null or contain equal sets of <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair'1{TKey}{TValue}"></see> items; otherwise, false.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key.</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="TValue">The type of the value.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="A">The first instance to compare</param>
        /// <param name="B">The second instance to compare</param>
        /// <returns>true if both instances are null or contain equal sets of <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair'1{TKey}{TValue}"></see> items; otherwise, false.</returns>
        public static bool AreBothNullOrEqualSets<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> A, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> B)
        {
            // XOR for null
            if ((A == null) ^ (B == null))
                return false;

            // Compare each value in set
            if (A != null)
                if (!A.OrderBy(x => x.Key).SequenceEqual(B.OrderBy(x => x.Key)))
                    return false;

            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compares two sequences are null or contain equal sets of items.
        /// Returns true if both instances are null or contain equal sets of <see cref="T:Common.FluentValidation.AreBothNullOrEqualSets`1"/> items; otherwise, false.
        /// </summary>
        /// ///  for more information.
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the enumerable.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="A">The first instance to compare</param>
        /// <param name="B">The second instance to compare</param>
        /// <returns>true if both instances are null or contain equal sets of <see cref="T:Common.FluentValidation.AreBothNullOrEqualSets`1"/> items; otherwise, false.</returns>
        public static bool AreBothNullOrEqualSets<T>(IEnumerable<T> A, IEnumerable<T> B)
        {
            // XOR for null
            if ((A == null) ^ (B == null))
                return false;

            // Compare each value in set
            if (A != null)
                if (!A.SequenceEqual(B))
                    return false;

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I searched and found a few hints, but have attempted several things with no luck. Best I can get is for it to just display "T" in the Intellisence balloon, which leaves something to be desired...

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe%28VS.85%29.aspx
- [reference to generic type in XML code comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030091/reference-to-generic-type-in-xml-code-comment)
- [How to reference generic classes and methods in xml documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532166/how-to-reference-generic-classes-and-methods-in-xml-documentation)
- [Generics in XML documentation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412865/generics-in-xml-documentation-issue?lq=1)
- [using see cref with < > characters in XML Documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828075/using-see-cref-with-characters-in-xml-documentation?lq=1)
- [XML Documentation: <see> tag with multiple generic type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526970/xml-documentation-see-tag-with-multiple-generic-type-parameters?rq=1)

**EDIT**:

Here's Microsoft doing it on the class level type params... but not on the constructor... So is this possible for methods/constructors? (ideally I want to show the types inlined with my comments, but the way it is in the example image below is perfectly acceptable as well)

[image: Microsoft Can do it]

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 2):

Though this is a very old question, I've found myself today struggling with the exact same issue - and I regret to say that it doesn't look like there's a real solution.

using `<see cref="Dictionary{int, string}">` will cause the following warning (at least on VS 2017):

> CS1584    XML comment has syntactically incorrect cref attribute 'Dictionary{int, string}'

When hovering over the green squiggle, VS will show a tool-tip saying (among other things):

> Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type. See also [error CS0081](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0081).

The only solution I came up with is simply to add a couple of paragraphs specifying the types of `TKey` and `TValue`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a <see cref="Dictionary{TKey, TValue}"/> that maps ints to strings.
/// <para>
/// TKey is <see cref="int"/>.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// TValue is <see cref="string"/>.
/// </para>
/// </summary>
public Dictionary<int, string> Map {get;}
```

Intellisence will show it like this:

> `Gets a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> that maps ints to strings.`
>   `TKey is int.`
>   `TValue is string.`

Comment: Better than nothing, I suppose, but doesn't really explain why it can't parse what was originally there. Annoying choices by Microsoft here. But what the # do we know?